# Existence of polynomial p such that $|f(x) − p(x^2)| < \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials, power-series, taylor-expansion

Let $f$ be a real valued continuous function on $\left[−1, 1\right]$ such that $f(x) = f(−x)$ for all $x \in \left[−1, 1\right]$.

Show that for every  $\epsilon > 0$  there is a polynomial  $p\left(x\right)$  with rational coefficients such that for every  $x \in \left[−1, 1\right]$, 
$$|f\left(x\right) − p\left(x^2\right)| < \epsilon$$.

I was trying something like this

$$f(x)=f(0)+\frac{f^{'}(0)}{1!}x+\frac{f^{''}(0)}{2!}x^2+\frac{f^{'''}(0)}{3!}x^3+\frac{f^{''''}(0)}{4!}x^4+\dots \dots$$

$$f(-x)=f(0)-\frac{f^{'}(0)}{1!}x+\frac{f^{''}(0)}{2!}x^2-\frac{f^{'''}(0)}{3!}x^3+\frac{f^{''''}(0)}{4!}x^4-\dots \dots$$

adding these two we get 
$$f(x)+f(-x)=2f(0)+2\frac{f^{''}(0)}{2!}x^2+2\frac{f^{''''}(0)}{4!}x^4+2\frac{f^{''''''}(0)}{6!}x^6+\dots \dots$$

Because $f(x)=f(-x)$
we have $$2f(x)=2f(0)+2\frac{f^{''}(0)}{2!}x^2+2\frac{f^{''''}(0)}{4!}x^4+2\frac{f^{''''''}(0)}{6!}x^6+\dots \dots$$

Hence $$f(x)=f(0)+2\frac{f^{''}(0)}{2!}x^2+\frac{f^{''''}(0)}{4!}x^4+\frac{f^{''''''}(0)}{6!}x^6+\dots \dots$$

Thus taking $$p(x)=f(x^{\frac12})=f(0)+\frac{f^{''}(0)}{2!}x+\frac{f^{''''}(0)}{4!}x^2+2\frac{f^{''''''}(0)}{6!}x^3+\dots \dots$$

This gives me $$|f\left(x\right) − p\left(x^2\right)|=0$$

But I want a polynomial $p(x)$ which should of finite degree. So I have trouble with this part

Can Someone write the answer of this question formally. I am not sure about presenting my answer.

Comment: Do you know Weierstrass approximation theorem?

Comment: is my approach wrong?

Comment: @Suraj The function is assumed to be continuous this does not guarantee a Taylor expansion.

Comment: @clark I see. Thanks. How do I proceed ahead then?

Comment: You can use Weierstrass approximation theorem and the denseness of polynomials with rational coefficients in  $C[a,b] $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not valid because $f$ need not admit a Taylor series expansion. $f(\sqrt {|x|})$ is a continuous function. By Wierstrass Theorem there is a polynomial $p$ such that $|f(\sqrt {|x|})-p(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$.  Replacing $x$ by $x^{2}$ we get $|f(x)-p(x^{2})| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Now use the fact that $f(-x)=f(x)$ to conclude that the inequality holds for $x \in [-1,0] $ also.